# Inject Default Firebase Config into Angular App

Tags: angular, firebase

I have the need to use the default configuration from the firebase hosting for an app because I am deploying it to multiple projects.

If this was a normal html app you would use:

```html
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="/__/firebase/6.1.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#reserved-urls -->

<!-- Initialize Firebase -->
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

But I am using an angular app so I want to inject it in the initialize of the app module. I tried to do something like this:

```js
let firebaseConfig = environment.firebase;

if (environment.production) {
  console.log('loading init');
  fetch('/__/firebase/init.json').then(async response => {
    firebaseConfig = await response.json();
  });
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
```

That is just part of my app module but you can kind of get the idea. If it is in production, I want to pull it from the `init.json` but if not I want to pull it from the environment setting.

And since this is an async operation, how can I make it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an option you can try:

**app.module.ts**

```ts
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule,
  ]
  ...
```

**main.ts**

```ts
import { FirebaseOptionsToken } from '@angular/fire';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

function loadConfig() {
  return environment.production ?
    fetch('/__/firebase/init.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
    : Promise.resolve(environment.firebase);
}

(async () => {
  const config = await loadConfig();

  platformBrowserDynamic([{ provide: FirebaseOptionsToken, useValue: config }])
     .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
     .catch(err => console.error(err));
})();
```

Comment: In case you are like me and thought that <script src="/__/firebase/6.1.0/firebase-app.js"></script> and <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script> were also necessary for this to work... they aren't. '/__/firebase/init.json' seems to be available immediately with no further scripts required.

Comment: At December 1st of 2021 the FirebaseOptionsToken didn't work with my current version of AngularFire, maybe because another code uses compat modules, so `FirebaseOptionsToken` should change to `FIREBASE_OPTIONS` from `"@angular/fire/compat"`, and add another provider for `AngularFireModule` (from same module).

Then you import and provide `AngularFireModule` in AppModule. https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2360#issuecomment-983545971