# use APP_INITIALIZER in other providers

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using APP_INITIALIZER hook to load some app configuration from a local json file. After the loaded configuration, I want to use it in another provider (setting BASE_PATH for my generated swagger-codegen services).

I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'api' of undefined`

The value I try to access `AppInitService.settings.api` is a static property on AppInitService. I suspect this is the problem, but as I understand the APP_INITIALIZER hook should guarantee to wait before continuing...

How do I wait for the value to be loaded in APP_INITIALIZER and ready to be reused in another providers `useValue`?

**app.module.ts**

```js
    export function initializeApp(appConfig: AppInitService) {
        return (): Promise<any> => appConfig.init()
    }

    @NgModule({
        declarations: [...],
        imports: [...],
        providers: [
            AppInitService,
            {
                provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
                useFactory: initializeApp,
                deps: [AppInitService],
                multi: true,
            },
            {
                provide: BASE_PATH,
                useValue: AppInitService.settings.api,
            },
        ],
```

**app.config.service.ts**

```js
    @Injectable()
    export class AppInitService {
        static settings: IAppConfig
        private conf: IAppConfig

        constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

        public getConf() {
            return this.conf
        }

        init() {
            const jsonFile = `assets/config/config.json`
            return this.http
                .get(jsonFile)
                .pipe(
                    tap((returnedConfig: IAppConfig) => {
                        console.log('returnedConfig', returnedConfig)
                        AppInitService.settings = returnedConfig
                        this.conf = returnedConfig
                    })
                )
                .toPromise()
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56431192/inject-default-firebase-config-into-angular-app/56431386#56431386

Answer (score 2):

You can use a factory provider.

```js
{
    provide: BASE_PATH,
    useFactory: (service: AppInitService) => service.conf, // doesn't need to be static
    deps: [AppInitService]
}
```

Angular will only call the factory function the **first** time the provider is resolved, but you are just *assuming* it will be resolve *later*. It might work for now, but could break later or never work at all.

Instead, use an observable as the injectable value.

```js
@Injectable()
public class AppInitService {
    public conf: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject(1);

    init() {
       const jsonFile = `assets/config/config.json`
       return this.http
            .get(jsonFile)
            .pipe(
                tap((returnedConfig: IAppConfig) => this.conf.next(returnedConfig))
            ).toPromise()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't get it to work though... Why did you use ReplaySubject instead of - say - BehaviorSubject?

Comment: @olefrank you don't want the observable to emit until a value is ready. BehaviorSubject will always emit a value, but ReplaySubject won't emit until at least `next()` is called once.

Comment: I use it like this: 
{
    provide: BASE_PATH,
    deps: [AppInitService],
    useFactory: (service: AppInitService) =>
        service.conf.subscribe(val => val.api.baseUrl),
},
But it returns [object object]

Comment: Could you please provide an example how to use your suggested solution with ReplaySubject?